# How to access network drive for dropping a file during automation run using Jenkins

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, network-drive

Not able to access network drive location using csharp code while running script through Jenkins

Tried with

```
File.Copy("sourcepathloc", "destpathloc")
```

It's working while running automation script from visual Studio but getting an error while running it through Jenkins.

Comment: If you log into your Jenkins host, can you access the network file path? What error does it give (permission error/timeout?)

Comment: No. Network path not accessible from Jenkins host system. Getting access issue there.

Comment: Then that is likely the issue you need to focus on. Once that is fixed, the Jenkins job should be able to access your network file path.

Comment: Actually, that network drive access can not be given to the jenkins host user( Due to restrictions). Is it possible using csharp code, file can be copy to the network drive with specific user credentials. Please let me know.